# Java MimeMessage to eml File with all attachments

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, james, eml, mime-message

I have an incoming `MimeMessage` in my **JAMES** mail server. I want to create an eml file dumping the message completely. I tried using the `writeTo` method of MimeMessage - resulting file contains only the text body of the email. The attachments are not written to the eml file.  My code is something like

```
String logFileName = "dumpNow.eml";
incomingEmail.getMessage().writeTo(new FileOutputStream(new File(logFileName)));
```

I do not get any multipart content in the dump. Is there any Util available to do this? **Apache Mimeutils** is also giving the same result.

Comment: That should work.  What version of JavaMail are you using?

Comment: There are some issues , if the message originated from Mac machines. I see problem only for those messages.

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail.  What's an example of a message that fails? How does it fail?  What version of JavaMail are you using?  Is it exactly a MimeMessage or is it a subclass?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
// Create your attachement file
File emlFile = new File("myFile.eml");
emlFile.createNewFile();
incomingEmail.getMessage().writeTo(new FileOutputStream(emlFile));

MimeBodyPart attachment = new MimeBodyPart();

DataSource source = new FileDataSource(emlFile);

attachment.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
attachment.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
attachment.setFileName("myFileName.eml");
attachment.setDescription("My file description");
attachment.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT);

multipart.addBodyPart(attachmentFile);
```

I think it is because you missed to set the header and the disposition in your code.

Hope it helps,

Comment: I think , this is not relevant to the question :-). I was mentioning about dumping a multipart content to a file (remote to local). Seems you got it reverse.

Comment: BTW, I had to parse the body tree for emails which had the multipart-mixed contents to do this.